# Collectd memcachec plugin broken?

Tags: bug-reporting, collectd

I'm trying to use the `memcachec` plugin to read data from the memcached, but when I'm using this config:

```
<Plugin "memcachec">
  <Page "plugin_instance">
    Key "KEY1"
    Server "localhost"
    ...
  </Page>
</Plugin>
```

I'm getting `memcachec plugin: Option 'server' not allowed here.`, if I remove the server option I get `memcachec plugin: 'Server' missing in 'Page' block.`. I've checked the sources of memcachec and there's this code (memcachec.c, line 329):

```
if (strcasecmp ("Server", child->key) == 0)
  status = cmc_config_add_string ("Server", &page->server, child);
if (strcasecmp ("Key", child->key) == 0)
  status = cmc_config_add_string ("Key", &page->key, child);
else if (strcasecmp ("Match", child->key) == 0)
  /* Be liberal with failing matches => don't set `status'. */
  cmc_config_add_match (page, child);
else
{
  WARNING ("memcachec plugin: Option `%s' not allowed here.", child->key);
  status = -1;
}
```

It seems like the second `if` should have been `else if` for the plugin to work. Is this a bug? Where do I report it? What's the proper way to fix it locally until the official fix arrives?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got your answer a long time ago, but it seems this has been fixed. Reporting bugs is best done using either the mailing list (see tag info), or opening an issue on github (https://github.com/collectd/collectd).